# OPENJSON Convert Value Column to Multiple Rows does not work

Tags: json, t-sql, open-json

I have a JSON file with a simple structure. I try to extract data into rows out of this JSON File.

The JSON File starts with:

```
[{"result":
[{"country":"Germany",
  "parent":"xxxx",
"city":"Reitbrook",
"latitude":"",
```

I tried this code, all successfully.
Look at the last 3 statement and their results. 
I would Expect multiple records at the SELECT last statement.
What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @details VARCHAR(MAX)

Select @details  =BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET 
 (BULK 'folder/cmn_location',   DATA_SOURCE='blogstorage',    SINGLE_CLOB) as JSON;

IF (ISJSON(@details) = 1)
    BEGIN  PRINT 'Imported JSON is Valid'     END
ELSE
    BEGIN  PRINT 'Invalid JSON Imported'      END



SELECT @details as SingleRow_Column

--delivers one row Where

--SingleRow_Column=[{"result":[{country":"Germany","parent":.....


SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@details, '$')

--delivers one row. Where 

--Key=0, value={"result":[{"country":"Germany","parent":"xxx".....


SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@details, '$.result')
```

--delivers no row at all

Now error messages, but just no data

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

Hint: I had to add some closing brackets...

```
DECLARE @YourJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'[{"result":
[{"country":"Germany",
  "parent":"xxxx",
"city":"Reitbrook",
"latitude":""}]}]';

SELECT B.*
FROM OPENJSON(@YourJson)        WITH(result NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.result)  WITH(country NVARCHAR(1000)
                                    ,parent NVARCHAR(1000)
                                    ,city NVARCHAR(1000) ) B;
```

The idea in short:

Your JSON is an array, containing at least one object `result`. (There might be more objects, but you did not show enough).

This object `result` is an array itself. Therefore we use the `WITH` in combination with `AS JSON` and another `APPLY OPENJSON` using the nested array returned as `A.result`.